# How to get the first match String using Regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have folowing code:

```
public class RegexTestPatternMatcher {
  public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "This is my first photo.jpg string and this my second photo2.jpg String";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\.jpg");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
    // check all occurance
    while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
  }
}
```

The Output is:

```
photo.jpg
photo2.jpg
```

I would like to select the first match so only **photo.jpg**, and skip the second photo2.jpg, I tried **matcher.group(0)**, but not worked, Any idea how to do that, Thanks.

Comment: Just remove the loop and call `matcher.find()` and `matcher.group()` once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop iterating after first match. Change `while` to `if`

```
if (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```